# Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop version with no Monitor mounted

Tags: server, monitor, teamviewer

I have a small server that I'm using as a Plex server and I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop version. I'm also using Teamviewer to connect and control my server.

However, when I disconnect my monitor, my screen on the server starts to make trouble by flashing and glitching. Then, when I connect my monitor again, all goes back to normal.

I have tried to install a fake monitor, but that did not help . . . it's still doing the same problem.

I really want to disconnect my monitor so I can use my monitor on my own computer again. - I hope someone understands my problem and can help me. Thanks!